# Path structure of an odd-looking higher inductive type.

Tags: fundamental-groups, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

Consider the (putative) higher inductive type $\mathtt{PNest}$, with the constructors:

- $\mathtt{base} : \mathtt{PNest}$
- $\mathtt{nest} : \mathtt{base} = \mathtt{base} \to \mathtt{base} = \mathtt{base}$

Firstly, is this actually a valid HIT?  I feel like it should be, but I know that the HoTT book says that path constructors taking other paths as parameters are "somewhat fishy," so I'm not sure if my intuition holds.

Secondly, if it *is* a valid HIT, what does its path structure look like?  I've been trying to figure this out on my own, but I'm no closer to an answer than when I started.  How does the path space $\mathtt{base} = \mathtt{base}$ behave?  Is $\mathtt{PNest}$ contractible, equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^1$, or something more complicated?  Even some pointers on what direction to look would be greatly appreciated!

---

EDIT:  In pursuit of the direction suggested by @ZhenLin's comment about "the free 'group with an endomap,'" is there a way to connect the type $\mathtt{base} = \mathtt{base}$ to a defined type that produces that structure explicitly?

Comment: I suspect this defines a [rose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_%28topology%29) of infinitely many circles.

Comment: My first guess is the same as @ZhenLin's.  But it seems quite tricky to list the generators of those circles, since in addition to the obvious nest(refl), nest(nest(refl)), etc. you'll also have nest(nest(refl).nest(refl)) which is different from nest(nest(refl)).nest(nest(refl)), and so on.

Comment: I had some idea that it might look like a tree structure, on some level, but no more intuition than that.  :/

Comment: Ah, good point. I was just thinking of iterates of `nest`. So perhaps it should be the free "group with an endomap" on one element?

Comment: @ZhenLin Isn't that basically what it's *defined* as, given that identity forms a groupoid?  Then again, maybe that's the best we can do...

Comment: @MikeShulman Is it O.K. if I ask this question on the HoTT mailing list?  It just doesn't seem to be getting much attention here.  :/

Comment: I think it would be the free group-with-an-endomap on *no* elements.  And no, it's not defined as that, any more than the loop space of the circle is defined as the free group on one element.  Feel free to ask on the HoTT list (as you've observed, not many homotopy type theorists pay attention to MSE), but I doubt you'll get a much better answer there.